# No space between three-digit table number and title in List of Tables (KOMA-script)

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, koma-script

I have KOMA script report in LyX (2.0.6 on Mac OS X 10.9.3) where there are more than 100 tables per chapter. For all the tables with more than thee digits (numbered chapter number dot table number) there is no space between the table number and the table caption in the List of Tables.

[image: tableof table space]
Unfortunately the example I give is not-so-minimal because the problem only occurs after table 100.

```
    %% LyX 2.0.6 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
\documentclass[english]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{report title}

\maketitle
\listoftables


\begin{table}[H]


\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{A table}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please share an MWE (minimal working example) which shows this error to us. Like this, we don't have to type everything in order to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance between numbers and titles in `scrreprt` is defined by `\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}`. The first value is the indent in front of the number, the second one the distance before the title. Just change the second value by your needs (in my example 3em).

The following example renews this command with the new value. The second line tells the LOF to behave like the LOT which will look nicer.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{scrreprt}
\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}} % original values in scrreprt
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}} % modified. 
\let\l@table\l@figure
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\setcounter{table}{98}
\begin{table}
\caption{Summary of...}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\caption{Correlation of...}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\caption{More stuff...}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is also an option for the KOMA-Script classes: `listof=flat`. Then all lists of floating environments will be printed similar to tables. The caption
numbers are in the first column, the caption texts in the second, and the page
numbers are in the third column. The width of the first column depends on the previous run. So you have to run twice when the contents of a list has changed.

```
\documentclass[listof=flat]{scrreprt}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\setcounter{table}{98}
\begin{table}
\caption{Summary of...}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\caption{Correlation of...}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
\caption{More stuff...}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]